# 'Picket' v. 'sit-in'

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When protesters pitch tents in front of a government building and refuse to go making some political demands, what do you call it? I consider two options: 'a tent sit-in' and 'a tent picket' (I want to mention tents).

[image]

Comment: Would you consider a [**protest camp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protest_camp)?

Comment: tent protest? tent camp? tent city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picket is a protest by strikers outside their workplace, to prevent others from working there.  The use is extended from an old sense in military use of a line of pikemen defending against cavalry.  If the protest is intended to stop people from accessing a the government building, then you might call it a picket.

A sit-in is another type of protest in which the protesters occupy a building and sit there. This isn't a sit-in, as they are not "in" the building.

This looks most like a "protest camp" (as suggested in the comments)

Comment: "from accessing a the government building" -  have you decided which one to put? because I am curious :)